# HTML helper DropDownList explained

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can someone please explain how this works? (which overload is being used)

```
@Html.DropDownList("FinancialYearID", "Select FY")
```

FinancialYearID is a SelectList in view bag. Why is it passed as a string?

Also how can I add custom attributes on the input element?
Adding a 3rd parameter

```
new { @class = "foo" }
```

doesn't work?

Is it possible to add data- attributes using the default helpers?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're calling [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504970%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) overload. This creates a dropdown list with the *name* "FinancialYearID" (which means that the selected value will bind to a model or ViewBag property called "FinancialYearID") and "Select FY" as the placeholder (empty) selection text.

If you want to add a class, you need the `DropDown(string, IEnumerable, string, object)` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FinancialYearID", null, "Select FY", new { @class = "foo" })
```

Here, you can also populate the DropDownList by passing in an `IEnumerable` (such as a `SelectList`) where I have passed `null`.

Yes, it is entirely possible to pass a data attribute. just replace the hyphen with an underscore:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("FinancialYearID", null,
                   "Select FY", new { @data_something = "foo" })
```

If you have a model property to which you're trying to bind the selected value, you can pass a lamba expression to indicate the property that you want to bind and the framework will generate the appropriate `name`:

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.FinancialYearID, MySelectList,
                   "Select FY", new { @data_something = "foo" })
```

I'd also generally advise putting the `SelectList` in the model on the initial GET request rather than using `ViewBag`.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you use 
`DropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string optionLabel)`

To acquire effect you want, you should use next code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FinancialYearID, (SelectList)ViewBag.FinancialYearID, "Select FY", new { @class = "foo" })
```

(overload is `DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
string, 
object)`)

or, if one of your SelectList marked as selected, use next code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FinancialYearID, (SelectList)ViewBag.FinancialYearID, new { @class = "foo" })
```

(overload is `DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
object)`)

P.S.
Don't forget to cast your ViewBag item to SelectList, because compiler would think that second parameter is object.

Comment: Can you also explain how does the 1st param work (lambda expr). What does it add to the input element?

Comment: It adds same html to the page, as method in your example (outputs select list with name/id equal to property name), but you can safely rename properties of your models and don't rely on magic strings without a special needs.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could have use the below one. For passing data attributes use underscore`_` like `new {@data_myname=value}`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

```
 public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

***Parameters***

htmlHelper

Type: `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`
 The HTML helper instance that this method extends.

name

Type: `System.String`
 The name of the form field to return.

selectList

Type: `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`
  A collection of SelectListItem objects that are used to populate the drop-down list.

htmlAttributes

Type: `System.Object`
 An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.

Return Value

Type: `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString`
An HTML select element with an option subelement for each item in the list.