# new SelectList combining two fields but getting only one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Im kinda stuck, I have a drop down that I am trying to combine two fields from the same table into. Its kinda working, here is what I get:
[The offending drop down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcVj1.png)

As you can see, im pulling stuff I dont want into it, and im not pulling in my last name.

Here is my edit controller:

```
var DocList =
            db.Doctors
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Value = s.ID,
                FirstN = s.FirstName,
                SurN = s.Surname,

            })
            ;
ViewBag.Doctor = new SelectList(DocList, "FirstN", "SurN", episode.Doctor.ID);
```

and here is my razor snippet:

```
@Html.DropDownList("docTest")
```

What do you guys think is going wrong here? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What do you mean by this code `ViewBag.DoctorOLD = new SelectList(DocList, "FirstN", "SurN", episode.Doctor.ID);`

Comment: And what is this `docTest` when you use `DoctorOLD` in `ViewBag`

Comment: Where are you binding the ViewBag.DoctorOLD in your razor view. Seems you are specified name of the drop down list only.

Comment: if some of the answers helped you below, even your own answer, refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you should populate your dropdown list like

```
ViewBag.Doctors = new SelectList(db.Doctors.Select(d => new { d.Id, FullName = d.FirstName + " " + d.LastName }), 
                "Id", "FullName");
```

And then in view create dropdown with razor

```
@Html.DropDownList("DoctorId", ViewBag.Doctors as SelectList, "Select doctor...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Your model for form that you are creating probably should have DoctorId property which you are binding from dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DoctorId, ViewBag.Doctors as SelectList, "Select doctor...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be needing to do something like this (it will give the dropdown the id of "docTest"):

```
@Html.DropDownList("docTest", (SelectList)ViewBag.DoctorOLD, "Place Holder Text", new { @class = "someClass" })
```

but you may need different functionality, I cannot tell from the amount of code supplied.You may also look into using `@html.DropDownListFor` if you need to bind the drop down value to a model property.

[This SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937439/html-helper-dropdownlist-explained) does a great job of explaining html helper drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the value to drop down list.Use below code to get the values

```
 @Html.DropDownList("docTest",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DoctorOLD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is the solution im still pretty green at this so where I came unstuck was knowing the overloads. Let me try to explain (and correct me if im wrong)

Okay so we invoke our list. Now our first overload is the ieneumerable, this gets our bunch of stuff we want in our list. Next we want our value field, which is the column in your table that other tables use to link to it, in most cases its the ID column.

Next is the string. In my case its "FullName" and is basically made up of the FirstName and Surname from within my Doctors table.

Anyway if your dyslexic like me just look at the code below and pick it apart :)

**The Controller:**

```
ViewData["docFullDetails"] =
            new SelectList((from s in db.Doctors
                            select new
                            {
                                FullName = (s.FirstName + s.Surname),
                                ID = s.ID
                            }),
            "ID",
            "FullName");
```

**The View:**

```
<div class="form-control">
                @Html.DropDownList("docFullDetails")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Doctor)

            </div>
```