# Trying to populate a DropDownList in Asp.Net Core Boilerplate Edit Modal?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am having trouble converting my int [StateID] to string [StateName] on my EditModal in ASP.Net Boilerplate template.

I can display the StateID but not the StateName

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Id", Model.States,
                            new
                              {
                                  @class = "form-control",
                                  id = "StateCombobox",                               
                                  
                              })
```

The dropdown populates with all the states, but I'm trying to display the stored value in the server as the selected value.

Any pointers would be most appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML helper DropDownList explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937439/html-helper-dropdownlist-explained)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `StateName` as `Text`,`StateId` as `Value` in SelectListItem.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class DropDownModel
    {

        public List<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }

    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult TestDropDown()
        {
           //set StateName as Text,StateId as Value
            DropDownModel d = new DropDownModel { States = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "state1" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "state2" } } };
            return View(d);
        }
```

View:

```
@model DropDownModel
@Html.DropDownList("Id", Model.States,
                           new
                             {
                                 @class = "form-control",
                                 id = "StateCombobox",

                             })
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am able to do that now. The next step is to pull the stateName value from the States table based on the StateID value in the Vendors table. I am new to using boilerplate and repositories. For me, it's more complicated than MVC scaffolding which uses ViewData and ViewBag. I have read the documentation on asp.net boilerplate's website and found some good explanations on Linq queries but no examples of what I'm trying to do. Their tutorial stops at the create task and doesn't continue further for editing. Again thanks.